# Flutter: How to set firebase uid to users document id?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

How to set firebase uid to users document id? i'm getting error as "uid is null". Here is my code.

```
FirebaseAuth.instance.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email:email, password: password).then((currentUser) => Firestore.instance
                                  .collection("users")
                                  .document(currentUser.uid)
                                  .setData({ "uid": currentUser.uid,


                                }));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can become the current user information with the .user ending and then you have access to the uid with currentUser.uid.

```
Future<void> createUser() async {
    final FirebaseUser currentUser = (await FirebaseAuth.instance.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: 'Test@gmail.com', password: '123456')).user;
    Firestore.instance.collection("users").document(currentUser.uid).setData({
        "uid": currentUser.uid,
      },
    );
  }
```

Comment: @HasithaErandaka great I am glad :) Can you please accept the answer so that other users can see that this answer is helpful? :)